# Using cdn instead of serving locally when using ng build --prod in Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am serving the Bootstrap framework locally for my development. Currently, the way I do it is adding my bootstrap in angular-cli.json like this

```
 "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

By the way, I use

> ng build --prod

when making my production build.

Is there a quick and nice trick to make use of CDN instead when I build it for production? 
Though I can achieve this by just manually add a bootstrap cdn in my index.html and delete the one in angular-cli.json. I am just wondering how you guys do it.

Comment: 'add a bootstrap cdn in my index.html '  <-- that.

Comment: @RosdiKasim Yes. I already stated that in my question. I am asking if there is a nice trick to do it automatically when building for production

Comment: if it was to be done "automatically" the cli will have to add a <link> tag with the url of the CDN to `index.html`. There is no need for this to be dynamic or handeled by the cli, so just add it to `index.html`.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam thank you for your comment but that is not what i'm looking for

Comment: @brijmcq were you able to find the solution?

Comment: @sam. Not yet :(

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but if you want to serve assets off a cdn (as in, `bundle.css`, `bundle.js`, `vendor.js`)

You can run `ng build --prod --deploy-url "https://cdn.yoursite.com/"`

Then in your index you'll see:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.yoursite.com/main.90c90d8887d1e50f79fb.bundle.js">
```

You will have to either upload the files during deployment or point your cdn at your app.

Bootstrap will be included in the bundle, and then served off your own cdn

Comment: thank you for your answer but it is not what I'm looking for. The one I want is something like this. I want to use the local copy of my bootstrap that is  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", when I'm just doing local development. When I build it for production, I want to use a cdn something like this https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css automatically. You may think that I'm lazy but I'm just curious if it is possible

Comment: I'd look into writing your own Grunt script that does the building, so it strips out the bootstrap references, runs ng build, adds the bootstrap cdn to the index.html file in the dist folder. I don't think theres anything off the shelf that does that for you.

Comment: I'm afraid that maybe true. The reason I have this in mind is that from Asp.net background, I can have something like this 
        <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
       </environment>
        <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
         </environment>
Anyways, thank you for your time